# Why was this mod flag denied?

Tags: discussion, flags

So the question is:

[How to get Derkeethus out of the cave?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/42979/how-to-get-derkeethus-out-of-the-cave/95286#95286)

and I flagged the answer by E.N (currently the one at the bottom) as 'not an answer' because I can't see how it answers the question being asked. It amounts to Q: "How do I get Derkeethus out of the cave?" A: "Get him out of the cave".

Am I missing something here? If I am, could someone please point it out to me so I can make sure not to make more unhelpful flags for this reason?

Comment: I agree that it's not an answer.

Comment: @fbueckert It's not a *good* answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not an answer flags are for using on posts [like this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/89053/14)

> Hey my question is the same but how can you get him out on the Xbox 360? I don't know what to do.

The answer you linked to *tries* to answer the question, fails, and it should be downvoted, not flagged.

Comment: To be fair, the NaA description says, `This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question`.  When a question asks, "How do I do X?" and an answer says, "Do X", that sounds exactly like Not an answer.  It assumes the solution to the question is trivial and can be completed without explanation.

Comment: I think it attempts to answer the question... it does a very bad job at it though.

Comment: I think the second sentence is an attempt to answer, but so obvious / not really helpful that maybe it should be a comment instead.  I'd say it's just a judgment call -- which, IMO, means marking the flag "helpful" even if you leave the answer alone.

Answer (score 5):

It is technically an answer. It's wrong and it doesn't answer the question, but it is an answer in the most basic sense that it provides information in response to a question.

Not an answer flags are to be used when an answer does not provide any information that could be construed as an answer, such as "Thanks" or "I had this problem too" or "Here is a link to something that might be related"